# getting error when retrive data from the database using entityframeworkmodel

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have silver light application.in the client side i have list of Guid using that Guid i can retrieve all data of customer when i am selecting 26 clients it works fine but when i tried to accessed data more then 26 clients it gives me error like

**Load Opration failed for query GetAtclientsERCWithAllInformation the remote server not found**

my client side look like

```
var query = formscontext.GetATClientsERCWithAllInformationQuery(guid);
        try
        {
            LoadOperation<ATClient> _loadReturnTypeOperation = formscontext.Load(query);
            _loadReturnTypeOperation.Completed += (s, e) =>
            {
            some code goes here 
            }
```

my server side look like

```
  [Query(HasSideEffects=true)]
    public IQueryable<ATClient> GetATClientsERCWithAllInformation(List<Guid> clientsGuids)
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.ATClients.Include("ClientEfileInfo").Include("ATClientImages").Include("ATPreparer").Include("ATPreparer.ATFirm").Include("ATClientReturns")
            .Include("ATClientReturns.ATForms").Include("ATClientReturns.ATForms.FormsMaster").Where(p => clientsGuids.Contains(p.ClientGUID));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that EF can't handle the query you requested. The error that silverlight is reporting is useless, you should look into the http response (remember that from an http perspective you're just doing a POST). 
Override the

```
protected override void OnError(DomainServiceErrorInfo errorInfo)
```

on your domainservice class in order to get the real error. 
Another quick way to get the error is to setup an http proxy and inspect the response (you can use fiddler + wcf binary inspector from msdn)

Comment: i have created override method but that method didn't executed, can you please tell what should i do ?

Comment: i tried to use fiddler but in fiddler all shows me in RED color and   result 504.

Comment: It seems that either the domainservice class can't be instantiated (code in constructor that can crash ?) or that the domainService module isn't loaded. Check both, put a breakpoint in your domain service contructor (if any) and check  your web config for something like 
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>  (continue)

Comment: and something like 
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>